# HTML, Streamlit: Changing problem of color of page border

Tags: python, html, css, python-3.x, streamlit

The code:

```
st.markdown('<style>body{border-color: white;}</style>',unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

The above code does not change the border color of the web page. How can we do this?

Comment: did you test this CSS directly on page using `DevTools` in Firefox/Chrome? Maybe `body` on your page doesn't have `border`. Usually `body` has border with size `0px` so it is invisible.

Comment: I tested empty page with your code and it adds this style. Problem is page has already complex CSS which puts `<div class="app">` on top and it hides `body`. There is also `<header>` which hides top of `body`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you must define the border-style. Therefore you can this code to add your style:

```
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: coral;
```

Comment: It didn't work too.